# Convert System::String^ to wchar_t in a C++ Wrapper that wraps a C# .Net DLL

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli

I have a C# .Net DLL Method that is wrapped in a C++ Method.

I have to do this because the dll must me used in an external program ( **Metatrader4** ) and it can manage only C++ native data type.

**In this moment I can make the call, all works fine, but i don't know how to return the exception variable to the C++ wrapper.**

This is the code:

### C# .Net Method

```
public int MT4_Order_pushToFirebase(string firebaseJsonUrl , string accountString ,string orderString,ref string exception) {
exception = "some error";
}
```

### C++ Method  ( Wrapper )

```
public: int __clrcall MT4_Order_pushToFirebase(wchar_t * firebaseJsonUrl, wchar_t * accountString, wchar_t * orderString, wchar_t * exception) {

            System::String^ S_firebaseJsonUrl = gcnew System::String(firebaseJsonUrl);
            System::String^ S_accountString = gcnew System::String(accountString);
            System::String^ S_orderString = gcnew System::String(orderString);
            System::String^ S_exception = gcnew System::String(exception);
            
            int res = robin->MT4_Order_pushToFirebase(S_firebaseJsonUrl, S_accountString, S_orderString, S_exception);                      

            return res;
        }

extern int MT4_Order_pushToFirebase(wchar_t * firebaseJsonUrl, wchar_t * accountString, wchar_t * orderString, wchar_t * exception) {
    RobinHoodCWrapper::RobinHoodCWrapper c;
    return c.MT4_Order_pushToFirebase(firebaseJsonUrl, accountString, orderString, exception);
}
```

If I try to call the DLL from the external program ( Metatrader4 ) , the method works fine but I cannot get exception variable back...

I dont know how to deal with **System::String** and **wchar_t** variables...

Thanks to support

Comment: C++/CLI has a `PtrToStringChars` function that accepts `System::String^`.  Make sure to use `pin_ptr` with it.

Comment: How does this function know how big a buffer has been passed as the `wchar_t* exception` parameter?

Comment: @BenVoigt can you show me an example ?
The exception value must be passed from Metatrader4 (the external program) to the C++ DLL wrapper that calls a C# Method and the string must be returned to the Metatrader4 program...